# Adding date picker to Google Sheets cells while data validation is customized

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have a column with customized data validation (custom formula) that accepts only dates, provided that a few other conditions are met.

How can I add a date picker to the cells of this column? Changing the Format did not help.

Edit: I want to pre-program my cells to have a date picker, just like they would have if the Data Validation criterion were set to Date.

A good workaround is provided by @user0, but I am still interested to know if this is directly possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a field display a calendar for picking a date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/how-do-i-make-a-field-display-a-calendar-for-picking-a-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Date picker in Google Sheets is available only when a cell contains a valid date. Empty cells can be pre-programmed to offer you the date picker (via Data Validation), but **not** if you use a custom formula in Data Validation.

[image: 0]

Your next best option is to have a chosen pre-programmed date, for example, like **`1/1/1900`** and have it hidden with white font color via Conditional Formatting. This way the date picker will be available in cells that look like they are empty until a different date is set.

[image: 0]

Comment: If you set the data validation to be “Date”, the empty cells are pre-programmed to have a date-picker. Is this an exception?

Comment: most likely yes. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this is it's link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EcDyivlTpDWC0j7McOcRTbjxeE4ikCjYbCr-xHjbFmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: nope, date picker in C column cant be forced as in G column. suggested CF workaround is your best option

Comment: @Aria answer updated